# Reactjs Async functions - function not finishing before next one starts

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I am trying to build a recipe database. I created a function for firebase that allows you to upload a photo to the storage and then get the url for that photo.

```
const handleUpload = async () => {
  const storage = firebase.storage();
  const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
  uploadTask.on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) => {},
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      storage
        .ref("images")
        .child(image.name)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          setImageUrl(url);
          console.log(url);
        });
    }
  );
};
```

Then I have a form where on the onSubmit, the photo upload function is supposed to fire so it can set the URL in the state, then fire the full upload which uploads the whole recipe to  firebase with the url included. It is being handled inconsistently where sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I have been trying different ways to make it work, but nothing seems to make it work perfectly. Here is the current onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
  await handleUpload().then(() => {
    createRecipe(values, imageUrl)
  })
}}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what is `createRecipe` and `handleUpload`. How does the whole component look like?

Comment: handleUpload uploads a picture to firebase storage which the picture is of the recipe, then sends the url of the photo back and sets it as a local state. createRecipe sends the values of the form plus the url from handleUpload to firebase to store the recipe in the database

Comment: The whole component is here: https://github.com/jacquelinetropp/worldwiderecipes/blob/master/src/components/RecipeForm/RecipeForm.js it is a form

Comment: You have no guarantee here that the state update of `imageUrl` will happen before `then`. You could use a `useEffect` to wait for `imageUrl` to update, or you could pass `createRecipe` to `handleUpload` to be called once you have the URL.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I dont know why I didn't think to pass it to handleUpload!

Answer (score 0):

React updates state async. You code relies on the fact that the state update `setImageUrl(url)` will be handled before `createRecipe` is called.

But there is no guarantee for that. That's basically a race between reacts internal dealings with state update, and your chain of async function.

Better to make `handleUpload` return a promise to the URL.

```
const handleUpload = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot) => {},
        (error) => {
            reject(error);
        },
        () => {
        storage
            .ref("images")
            .child(image.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
                resolve(url);
            });
        }
    );
  }
};
```

This way handleUpload will actually return the url when you await it.

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
  await handleUpload().then((url) => {
    createRecipe(values, url)
  })
}}
```

Also note that mixing async/await and then/catch/finally is considered bad practice.

I strongly recommend going with async/await only when you can.

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
  try {
      const url = await handleUpload()
      createRecipe(values, url)
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
}}
```